# Simple has_many through query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have `Event`-`Tag` association through `Tagging`.
In array `tags = %w(tag1 tag2 tag3)` I have tag names. I'd like to get all events tagged with one or more tags from this array. How can I do this?

Comment: TRy this `Event.includes(:tag).where(tag: tags)` or is relationship is has_many as `event - tags` then `Event.includes(:tags).where(tag: tags)`

Comment: `tags ` in where is your `array`

Answer (score 0):

Write a scope on Tag

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_names(names)
    where(name: names)
  end
end
```

Then write a scope on Event

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.for_tags(tag_names)
    joins(:tags).
    merge(Tag.with_names(tag_names))
  end
end
```

Query for Events with tags like

```
tags = %w(tag1 tag2 tag3)
Event.for_tags(tags)
```

You might need to call `uniq` if you don't want duplicate Events that match more than one Tag.

```
Event.for_tags(tags).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer, thanks to Sontya's comment.

`Event.includes(:tags).where(tags: {name: tags})` or
`Event.includes(:tags).where("tags.name IN (?)", tags).references(:tags)`